# Cannot import Pycurl: "libcurl link-time version is older than compile-time version"

Tags: osx-lion, python-2.7, libcurl, pycurl

I'm encountering difficulties importing pycurl.

```
>>> import pycurl
Fatal Python error: pycurl: libcurl link-time version is older than compile-time version
Abort trap: 6
```

I'm running OS X Lion and Python 2.7.1.

Any pointers would be much appreciated. My search for this issue on site turned up empty-handed.

Thanks,

Ben